# How to know a node is root in Virtual TreeView?

Tags: delphi, root, virtualtreeview

I am using Virtual Tree View. Is there a reliable way to know if a node is root or not?

I try to use

```
if not Assigned(Node.Parent) then
  Output('This is root')
else
  Output('This is not root')
```

But does not work.

I try to use

```
if Node = tvItems.RootNode then
  Output('This is root')
else
  Output('This is not root')
```

But does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate root node in `VTV` (or `VST`) is a special invisible node, which acts as parent for all user created root nodes (nodes created with `parent = nil`). This special invisible node has by design its `NextSibling` and `PrevSibling` properties set to point to itself.

To detect whether a node is root node (in the sense of user created root) you can e.g. do:

```
procedure TForm16.tvItemsNodeClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  const HitInfo: THitInfo);
begin
  if HitInfo.HitNode.Parent.NextSibling = HitInfo.HitNode.Parent then
    Caption := 'Root node'
  else
    Caption := 'Not root node';
end;
```

Alternatively, as OP commented, and without using internal implementation details:

```
procedure TForm16.tvItemsNodeClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  const HitInfo: THitInfo);
begin
  if HitInfo.HitNode.Parent = Sender.RootNode then
    Caption := 'Root node'
  else
    Caption := 'Not root node';
end;
```

Ref: TBaseVirtualTree.RootNode Property (in Help)

Comment: Thank you very much. I also find another way to check: if HitInfo.HitNode.Parent = tvItems.RootNode then...