# Parent of RootNode of TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

According to documentation, property RootNode of TVirtualStringTree is a hidden node, parent of all user created nodes. But the Parent of the RootNode is set. I am facing the following problem:

Sometimes, when closing a form that have a TVirtualStringTree in it, I get an access violation error. Debugging, the error occurs when is tryng to access the Name property of the componente (virtualstringtree). If I try to evaluate Name property, I get "Inaccessible value". Digging in the problem, I found out that the Name property of a component [cannot be changed in runtime](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_Name.html):

> Warning: Changing Name at runtime causes any references to the old
> name to become undefined. Any subsequent code that uses the old name
> will cause an exception.

It happend that I am not changing this in my code. Using a data breakpoint in the Name property, I saw that it was changing in a virtualstringtree loop, something like this (example code that I am using in a sample app to test the problem, but production code is similar):

```
var
  N: PNode;
  P: PVirtualNode;
begin
  P := tree.FocusedNode;
  while Assigned(P) do
  begin
    N := tree.GetNodeData(P);
    P := P.Parent;
  end;
```

The GetNodeData is the following:

```
 if (FNodeDataSize <= 0) or (Node = nil) or (Node = FRoot) then
    Result := nil
  else begin
    Result := PByte(@Node.Data) + FTotalInternalDataSize;
    Include(Node.States, vsOnFreeNodeCallRequired); // We now need to call OnFreeNode, see bug #323
  end;
```

Giving that I have the following tree:

```
Node 1
  Node 2
    Node 3
```

When the Node 3 is selected, the loop is executed 5 times. 3 in my created nodes, then the RootNode (hidden), and then the Parent of the root. Only the Parent of the parent root node is nil. In the GetNodeData method is verified if it is the root node, returns nil. But for this parent of the root, since it is not the root, enters in else code. Now here is the problem:

Address of the Name property of the virtualstrintree is $141B9768

Address of the States property of the parent of the root node is $141B976A

When putting the data breakpoint in Name property, it gets changed at this point:

```
Include(Node.States, vsOnFreeNodeCallRequired);
```

and generating the AV.

I know I can change the loop, to check the root node [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58057439/how-to-know-a-node-is-root-in-virtual-treeview), but I want to understand this, so I maybe fix the component (if it is a component bug), instead of my code.

Code:

```
type
  TNode = record
    Text: string;
  end;
  PNode = ^TNode;
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  N1, N2, N3: TNode;
  TreeNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  N1.Text := 'Node 1';
  TreeNode := tree.AddChild(nil, PNode(N1));

  N2.Text := 'Node 2';
  TreeNode := tree.AddChild(TreeNode, PNode(N2));

  N3.Text := 'Node 3';
  TreeNode := tree.AddChild(TreeNode, PNode(N3));
end;
```

Just put a tree and a button in the form, I put the loop in click of the button.

Comment: Are you using the lates version from https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView.git/trunk ?

Comment: You talk about a sample app to test the problem. Can you make its source available somewhere?

Comment: @fpiette its just a project with a tree, and creates 3 nodes in FormCreate. No worth make it available, what matters is the loop itself. Using version 5.3.0

Comment: the idea is that I can copy your code to reproduce your problem without working to much myself. So yes, it is worth to make it available. Since it is short - as you said - you can edit your question and add that code.

Comment: @fpiette sorry man, I edited the post

Comment: There are already two answers and you marked one as best answer. Isn't it satisfying for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the documentation: (e.g.)
https://documentation.help/VirtualTreeview/TBaseVirtualTree_RootNode.html

says (emphasis mine)

> property RootNode: PVirtualNode;
>
> Description
>
> For anchoring the tree
> hierarchy an internal tree node is maintained which is mostly just
> like any other tree node but has sometimes differently handled. The
> root node is always expanded and initialized. **Its parent member points
> to the treeview to which the node belongs to and its PreviousSibling
> and NextSibling members point to the root node itself to make it
> possible to actually recognize this node**.
>
> Notes
>
> You should not use the root node to iterate through the tree. It
> is only publicly accessible because it is the parent of all top level
> nodes and can be used to test a node whether it is a top level node or
> not.

Secondly

In your code

```
var
  N: PNode;
  P: PVirtualNode;
begin
  P := tree.FocusedNode;
  while Assigned(P) do
  begin
    N := tree.GetNodeData(P);
    P := P.Parent;
  end;
```

you are unconditionally traversing upwards past the internal root node because you are not checking for `P` being the internal root, by comparing with `tree.RootNode` (or comparing with `P.NextSibling`).

Perhaps changing the

```
while Assigned(P) do
```

condition to

```
while P <> tree.RootNode do
```

would suit you

Comment: Thanks Tom. Like I said in the end of my post, I know my loop is wrong because does not check for root, but like I said, even so I think I could also modified the method GetNodeData, becase it checks the root node (to return nil), but not its parent, and changes a different space in memory.

Comment: So, I will fix the loop, and also change the GetNodeData to check if its not the tree itself, just in case other loops exists. Thanks

Comment: @Rodrigo, not sure why you would want to change `GetNodeData()`. What is wrong with doing as it is designed to be done? I mean, you will lose compatibility. Whenever you might update to a newer version you would need to remember to apply your modification. So, really, why?

Comment: its a legacy 2 million+ lines project. I cant garantee that everywhere uses the loop correctly. The call of Include in GetNodeData method changes an invalid space of memory when using this kind of loop (yes, I know now its wrong, but I am pretty sure that exists other code like this somewhere). It makes sense, since already checks if Node parameter is the root, also checks if it is Self, also returns nil

Comment: This was the most hard AV that I had to track, because it was changing the Name property of the tree, in the call of Include, and it was very intermittent. So I think it makes sense to add this check

Comment: Thansk for the help @Tom

Comment: @RodrigoCaetano There is no change of Name property here. The cause for AV is that Root note Parent property is pointing to TVirtualStringTree components. So when you try to access it as TTreeNode AV is triggered. Read the bolded part of Tom's answer again.

Comment: @SilverWarior I readed Toms answer, I dont think you understood the problem. Yes, my problem was that it was changing the Name property. Read my post. The AV was not triggered in the GetNodeData. It was triggering when closing the form, when tried to access the Name property (read the embarcadero link in my post). The problem is that when trying to access Node.States (here Node is PVirtualNode, not TTreeNode, so an AV does not necessary triggers), its address is very close to Name address, and the call to Include is the problem

Comment: Now, after Tom's answer (yes, I could have readed the documentation more carefully), I understand why address of Name property its very close to "node.states", because node its actually the tree itself.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, using my example: a tree with 3 nodes. Debug the loop when reach for the fifth time, and enter the `GetNodeData` code. The Node parameter is the tree itself. Evaluate, in the `GetNodeData`, the `Node.States` and `Self.name`. In my test app, it returns `$2E71F9A` for `@Node.States` and `$2E71F98` for `@Self.Name`

Comment: Yes, @Rodrigo, I first misread your earlier comment, and answered, but removed my comment as irrelevant. I think the matter is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to Tom's answer, and the documentation of the component, the parent of RootNode is acctually the tree itself. So, when making the loop with the `Parent = nil` as point of stop, when reaching the parent's root (tree), the code `Include` in `GetNodeData` is executed, and, in my case, when accessing the `State` property, its address was very close to Name address of the treee, because the address of "node" was the tree.

So, I fix the loop to check for `Node <> Tree.RootNode` and also fix the `GetNodeData` to also check if Node is Self: `or (Node = Pointer(Self)`, **just in case other code in my application (legacy of 2 million+ code) uses the same wrong loop**:

Before:

```
function TBaseVirtualTree.GetNodeData(Node: PVirtualNode): Pointer;
begin
  Assert(FNodeDataSize > 0, 'NodeDataSize not initialized.');
  if (FNodeDataSize <= 0) or (Node = nil) or (Node = FRoot) then
    Result := nil
  else begin
    Result := PByte(@Node.Data) + FTotalInternalDataSize;
    Include(Node.States, vsOnFreeNodeCallRequired); // We now need to call OnFreeNode, see bug #323
  end;
end;
```

After:

```
function TBaseVirtualTree.GetNodeData(Node: PVirtualNode): Pointer;
begin
  Assert(FNodeDataSize > 0, 'NodeDataSize not initialized.');
  if (FNodeDataSize <= 0) or (Node = nil) or (Node = FRoot) or (Node = Pointer(Self)) then
    Result := nil
  else begin
    Result := PByte(@Node.Data) + FTotalInternalDataSize;
    Include(Node.States, vsOnFreeNodeCallRequired); // We now need to call OnFreeNode, see bug #323
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I emphasized the reason for this modification, to prevent that somebody else in the future thinks it would serve them.